# Rewriting depreciated php class call to Twig_Environment

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, twig

So I was running into this error in one of our old Page.php files after upgrading our version of Twig in our terribly dated web apps.

```
Error : Class 'Twig_Environment' not found
```

According to [this](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/3319) Github post, you can't use non-namespaced classes anymore.

The original code snippet looks like this:

```
    /* TWIG */
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(TEMPLATE_PATH);
    $twig = Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'cache' => false
    ));
```

Could I please get some help properly updating this use the class in my Twig/ directory without throwing a darn hissy fit?

I've been experimenting with defining the Twig path in our config file(forgive the messy directory):

```
define("TWIG_PATH", dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])."/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/");
```

Then in my Page.php file I tried using `Twig::Environment` and `\Twig\Environment` instead of `Twig_Environment` with no luck.

I also tried explicitly writing the path in the header `require TWIG_PATH."Environment.php";`

It just throws a `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Twig' not found`

I'm being a dingus somewhere here, and could really use another set of eyes on it. I'm also not a Twig expert, so I'm basically tackling these depreciation errors as they pop up.

I understand using namespaces properly is a really common question, but I know Twig s more of a niche package, so I figured anyone in the future running into my issues could use this post as a resource.

Edit: I may have answered my own formatting question by finding Twig's API documentation: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html

Will update post if this works.

Edit 2: So I have the error changing now. It supposedly can find the file directory I gave it, but is now spitting out:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Twig_Loader_Filesystem, because the name is already used in...
```

Well I'm at a loss at this point. Even following the Twig documentation it isn't being happy. I want to use the class, not declare again.

Comment: This looks like an [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) issue. If your install is as old as you claim, you might not be using one. Introducing [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) to manage your dependencies might be your best bet. And some refactoring tool like [rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/issues/137) to upgrade your codebase. Good luck!

Comment: Hey msg, this client's webapp does actually have an autoload.php file, and there is a composer subdirectory with multiple autoload files, inlucuding `autoload_classmap`, `autoload_namespaces`, etc... So let me investigate that before my shift ends, and I may get back to you tomorrow, if you don't mind.

Comment: Then, if you tried updating the twig install manually it might have caused problems. Try familiarizing yourself with [the basics](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) and make sure the project is using it. From there try to list the project dependencies and dumping the autoload files again.

Comment: Any reason for the upgrade? I mean, even after you get the new twig version running, you will be forced to skim every template for possible errors due to features being added/removed/adjusted

Comment: It has known incompatibilities with our updated version of PHP we are running, so its causing feature breaking errors. Upgrading to get the patch was the only way, sadly. So here I am down this rabbit hole and hurting my reputation asking weird questions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question was silly, but easy to overlook.

The newest version of Twig can't use non-namespaced function calls.

So to properly fix it, I had to use an explicit file path.

```
require_once ROOT_PATH."/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php";
```

Note that your mileage may vary depending on how your file structure is organized. Additionally, you can clean up your files by using these namespace definitions in your global config file.

So my PHP file is properly "talking" with all of the Twig classes I need. My webapp still isn't working, and is now throwing a `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError`, but in the scope of my original question, I've answered it.